# setting up continuous deployment via travis ci for docusaurus - what github scopes to use?

Tags: github, travis-ci, docusaurus

According to https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/publishing#using-travis-ci in order to use Travis CI to do continuous deployments to github pages you need to "*Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and generate a new personal access token*".

When I do that I'm presented with a bunch of "scopes" to select:

[image]

Which ones should I select? If I had to guess I'd guess the repo "scopes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected all the repo "scopes" and it seems to be working correctly.

It'd be cool if the documentation mentioned which scopes were needed but whatever